# Piping PCM data from FFMPEG to another process with Python subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am trying to transcribe a podcast. To do so, I am decoding the mp3 stream with FFMPEG, and piping the resulting PCM output to the speech recognition component. My code looks like this.

```
mp3=subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg','-i',audio_url,
                              '-f','s16le','-ac','1','-ar','16000','pipe:0'],
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sphinx=subprocess.Popen(['java','-jar','transcriber.jar'],
                                stdin=mp3.stdout,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Where `audio_url` is the url of the mp3 file.

When I try to run this, it hangs. It appears that feeding the decoded PCM data through the pipe has deadlocked. What can I do to fix this? The size of the output data is likely to be too big for `subprocess.Popen.communicate` to be an option, and explicitly calling `mp3.stdout.close()` has had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Your `pipe` number is incorrect. The correct values are:

- `pipe:0` - stdin
- `pipe:1` - stdout
- `pipe:2` - stderr

You can use:

- `pipe:1`, or
- just `pipe:`, as the default for output is stdout, or
- just use `-`

See [FFmpeg Documentation: pipe protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `pipe:0` won't connect to `mp3.stdout`. I used `-` instead and now it's working.